# Why does light($color,50%) parse to white?

Tags: css, sass

This sass snippet:

```
$red: #f00

$lightred: lighten($red, 50%)

body
  background: $lightred
```

Is parsed to:

```
body {
  background: white; }
```

If you instead do 45% instead of 50%, it seems to work as expected:

```
$lightred2: lighten($red, 45%)
...
background-color: #ffe5e5
```

**Why is this turning into white instead of the expected 50% of red?**

You can see it in action here http://tinkerbin.com/OefelPoi

(Note - the save function seems to have a bug, on the css area, select Sass Old Syntax again, and rerun)

**Update -**

Ends up what I wanted was to mix in white with the original color to get a tinted shade:

```
mix($color,white, 10%)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because lighten function is described on HSL colors and your red color #f90 is translated as hsl(0, 100%, 50%)

so lighten($lightred, 50%) is equal to hsl(0, 0, 100%), or white

Comment: Well that makes alot of sense. Do you know how to get a lighter version of a given color properly?

Comment: Perhaps just down the percentage then?